# Сортировка datagridview без сортировки источника данных

Tags: c#, datagridview

Можно ли отсортировать строку в datagridview, так ,чтобы в строке было и численное значение отсортированное в порядке возрастания или убывания и слово BTC , при этом не трогать источник этих данных?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(На скриншоте видно,что сейчас сортировка происходить только по первой цифре в строке)

P.S знаю ,что не стоит использовать datagridview ,как хранилище информации, но по другому пока не могу сделать т.к объём знаний не велик

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[2], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Comment: На скриншоте сортировка происходит используя этот код. У меня вся проблема заключается в том, что в строке есть не только число , но и буквы

Comment: Вы хотите строку сортировать по нескольким столбцам?

Comment: я хочу отсортировать 3 столбик , по возрастанию чисел в нем, при этом ,чтобы текст BTC остался

Comment: а Вы не хотите их на 2 столбца резделить?

Comment: нет. т.к я хочу ,чтобы единица измерения была в той же строке, что и само значение

Comment: тогда придется писать свой Comparer: IComparer и переписывать метод сортировки. Пример можно посмотреть здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-sorting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control. Берете значение столбца как строку, находите в ней пробел, делите на две подстроки(значение и тип валюты) и сравниваете под двум значениям